# Using regular expression find all occurrences of word which not start with given words

Tags: regex

I would like to build regular expression which will find all the places where the word 'Star' occurs. The condition is, there can't be a dot or word 'Black' before the 'Star' word.

E.g.

Blah *BlackStar* blah *.Star* blah **GreenStar** blah *Red.Star* blah blah **RedStar**

Only bolded occurrences should be returned. The italic occurrences should be ignored.

So far I've created the regular expression

```
\w*(?<!Black)Star
```

which checks only one condition if the word 'Star' not starts with the word 'Black'.

I want to find some way to add more conditions to it.

Any ideas?

Comment: `\w*(?<!\.|Black)Star` should work in PCRE but in python use: `\w*(?<!Black)(?<!\.)Star`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use:

```
\w*(?<!\.|Black)Star
```

that should work in PCRE but if using `python` use this regex with 2 different negative lookbehind assertions:

```
\w*(?<!Black)(?<!\.)Star
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/jhkDDF/1)